# Call function without resetting variables

Tags: python, variables

I am making a card game, when it gets to the end I want people to be able to play more rounds but when it replays it must go through the variables again.. resetting the score. I am looking for a way to fix it without a whole new block of complicating code, I'm hoping I'm just missing a really easy fix.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Imports

import time


def play_game():

    # Variables

    acard = int()
    bcard = int()
    apoints = int()
    bpoints = int()

    # Repeat

    repeat = True

    # Hand out cards

    print 'Cards have been served'
    input('\nPress Enter to Reveal')

    # Cards Turn

    time.sleep(0.5)
    t = time.time()
    acard = int(str(t - int(t))[2:]) % 13
    print '\nYour card value is ' + str(acard)

    time.sleep(0.1)

    t = time.time()
    bcard = int(str(t - int(t))[2:]) % 13

    # Number Check & Point Assign

    time.sleep(2)
    if acard > 5:
        apoints += 1
        print '\nYour points have increased by one, your total is now ' \
            + str(apoints)
    if acard < 5:
        apoints -= 1
        print '\nYour points have decreased by one, your total is now ' \
            + str(apoints)
    if bcard > 5:
        bpoints += 1
        print '\nYour opponent got ' + str(bcard) \
            + ', their points have increased by one,\ntheir total is now ' \
            + str(bpoints)
    if bcard < 5:
        bpoints -= 1
        print '\nYour opponent got ' + str(bcard) \
            + ', their points have decreased by one,\ntheir total is now ' \
            + str(bpoints)

    # Card Reset

    bcard = 0
    acard = 0

    # Shuffle

    input('\nPress enter to shuffle deck')
    print '\nCards being shuffled'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '.'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '.'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '.'
    print 'Cards have been shuffled'
    global enda
    global endb
    enda = apoints
    endb = bpoints


# Loop

time.sleep(1)
answer = 'y'
while answer.lower() == 'y':
    play_game()
    answer = input('\nDo you wish to play again? (Y/N)')

# Scores

if enda > endb:
    print '\nYou Win!'
    print '\nScores'
    print 'You: ' + str(enda) + ' Opponent: ' + str(endb)

if endb > enda:
    print '\nYou Lost!'
    print '\nScores'
    print 'You: ' + str(enda) + ' Opponent: ' + str(endb)
```

Comment: Python does not require you to 'declare' variables; `acard = int()` is just the same as `acard = 0`, but the line is redundant, really.

Comment: Instead of using digits from the time for your random values, I suggest using the `random` module. It will be much more random!

Comment: For this I would use a class and set the __init__ values as your variables (self.acard, self.bcard, etc.) and just create a new instance of the class once a new game starts. @MartijnPieters you might not need to declare variables in python, but if you want to iterate across multiple functions with the same variables you need to store them somehow.

Comment: acard = int() is the same so it resets it again

Comment: I originally this without libraries and forgot to modify that

Comment: Could you give me a practical example Colin? My code but corrected and explained please?

Comment: @ColinMcGrath: sure, but that does not mean you need to use a line like `acard = int()`; Python assignment statements to bring names into existence. Creating a state class is an excellent way to answer this question, I was merely pointing out an obvious flaw in the current coding style.

Comment: Yeah. And @AshleyMcManamon sure give me a few minutes and I'll turn your code into functional class coding

Comment: @AshleyMcManamon check below, I converted your code to class based python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably use an object oriented way to write this with class-level variables, but if you want to keep the code as close to what you have now, you could move your score variables outside the method:

```
apoints = 0
bpoints = 0

def play_game():
    global apoints
    global bpoints
    ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work, before gives me "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'apoints' referenced before assignment" and after means they aren't assigned yet.

Comment: Set all the variables equal to zero then add onto them inside the function

Comment: Doesn't work, before gives me "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'apoints' referenced before assignment"

Comment: The answerer forgot to mention that `play_game` needs to declare that it's using the global variables with `global apoints, bpoints` for assignment to work.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right. I'm so used to class programming I always forget that a basic function needs that reference

Comment: @user2357112 I added the global usage to my answer, sorry about that. It was an import thing to leave out. Mark Wilkin's answer explains why this is needed.

Comment: This one worked in the end, @user2357112 thanks that was leading it to not work.

Comment: I would also use if __name__ == __main__: to hold the code your executing at the bottom of the module as well. It's prevents minor problems, but it's good practice. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this would probably be to make a class and store all the variables you want to stay consistent throughout each round. I also don't believe this would be too much of a complicated block of code.

```
class GameVariables(object):

      def __init__(self):
           self.acard = 0
           self.bcard = 0
           self.apoints = 0
           self.bpoints = 0

      def reset(self):
           self.acard = 0
           self.bcard = 0
           self.apoints = 0
           self.bpoints = 0

    #need to initialize class.
    gamevar = GameVariables()
```

However as others have stated setting a variable = to int() is not needed in python. A better approach would be to just set it equal to some number:

`self.acard = 0`

This will keep your variables unchanged after the class is intialized until you call the reset method contained in the class.

To do so, call it like any other function but with the class name prepended.

`gamevar.reset() #this will reset variables.`

This will become especially useful has your games get larger and more complex. hope this helps.

Comment: That's not really python. It won't do what is required.

Comment: I see where this goes and thought it would work but I get this error "TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: It's almost Python, but the syntax is messed up. `class` is miscapitalized, `self` is missing everywhere, the `int()` calls are bizarre, the semicolon is redundant, and the class should inherit from `object`.

Comment: My apologies I hit the submit button too quickly. should work now

Answer (score 1):

It is in the nature of functions that their variables are initialised on each call. The point is that they work the same way every time.

If you want variables to persist, and be associated with functions, you use an object. This also allows you to break your giant lump of code into smaller functions.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change you can make would be to make those variables "global."

So, for example:

```
a = 5

def myfunc():
    print a
    a = 7

myfunc()
```

will not work because the assignment to `a` in `myfunc()` makes Python think that you are declaring a second, local variable `a` in the function.  You can use the global variable by doing this:

```
a = 5

def myfunc():
    global a
    print a
    a = 7

myfunc()
```

This explicitly states that you want all references to `a` inside your function to refer to the globally defined `a`.

What can be confusing is that if you're not assigning to `a` in the function, it will treat the variable defined outside the function as within the function's scope:

```
a = 5

def myfunc():
    print a

myfunc()
```

(This prints the number 5.)

Edit:  The other answer that recommends using a class is a solution that offers many benefits.  Using many global variables in a complex program reduces maintainability by forcing those variables to share one namespace, and making less explicit the possible side-effects that one function might have on another, since with a number of global variables you may not be able to tell easily where a particular variable is being changed.

However, if you're going to adopt a class-based approach to your problem, you'd be best off spending some time getting familiar with the language of object-oriented programming and design, since some of the behavior of the code you'll be writing may not be clear until you've gotten your head around the concepts.

In your code, making those variables global would change this part:

```
def play_game():

    # Variables

    acard = int()
    bcard = int()
    apoints = int()
    bpoints = int()
```

to this:

```
acard = int()
bcard = int()
apoints = int()
bpoints = int()

def play_game():

    # Variables

    global acard
    global bcard
    global apoints
    global bpoints

# etc.
```

One more thought:  Using something like

```
apoints = int()
```

because you wish to "declare" a variable as an integer probably doesn't have the effect that you think it does.  It is perfectly valid in Python to do this:

```
apoints = int()
print(apoints)

apoints = 5.0
print(apoints)

apoints = "My string"
print(apoints)
```

so making `apoints` an int does not make the variable an integer always and forever.  You're probably better off assigning an explicit value to the variable:

```
apoints = 0
```

This property of Python variable typing is called "duck typing."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code converted into class-based programming:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Imports

import time

class Play_Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.apoints = 0
        self.bpoints = 0

    def play_game(self):

        repeat = True
        print 'Cards have been served'
        raw_input('\nPress Enter to Reveal')

        # Cards Turn

        time.sleep(0.5)
        t = time.time()
        acard = int(str(t - int(t))[2:]) % 13
        print '\nYour card value is ' + str(acard)

        time.sleep(0.1)

        t = time.time()
        bcard = int(str(t - int(t))[2:]) % 13

        # Number Check & Point Assign

        time.sleep(2)
        if acard > 5:
            self.apoints += 1
            print '\nYour points have increased by one, your total is now ' \
                + str(self.apoints)
        elif acard < 5:
            self.apoints -= 1
            print '\nYour points have decreased by one, your total is now ' \
                + str(self.apoints)
        elif bcard > 5:
            self.bpoints += 1
            print '\nYour opponent got ' + str(bcard) \
                + ', their points have increased by one,\ntheir total is now ' \
                + str(self.bpoints)
        elif bcard < 5:
            self.bpoints -= 1
            print '\nYour opponent got ' + str(bcard) \
                + ', their points have decreased by one,\ntheir total is now ' \
                + str(self.bpoints)
        else:
            pass

        # Shuffle

        raw_input('\nPress enter to shuffle deck')
        print '\nCards being shuffled'
        time.sleep(1)
        print '.'
        time.sleep(1)
        print '.'
        time.sleep(1)
        print '.'
        print 'Cards have been shuffled'
        return

    def check_winner(self):
        if self.apoints > self.bpoints:
            print '\nYou Win!'
            print '\nScores'
            print 'You: ' + str(self.apoints) + ' Opponent: ' + str(self.bpoints)

        else:
            print '\nYou Lost!'
            print '\nScores'
            print 'You: ' + str(self.apoints) + ' Opponent: ' + str(self.bpoints)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    time.sleep(1)
    answer = 'y'
    current_game = Play_Game()
    while answer.lower() == 'y':
        current_game.play_game()
        current_game.check_winner()
        answer = raw_input('\nDo you wish to play again? (Y/N)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your variables outside the function and set the ones that you're using += on to 0 and since you're setting the value of acard and bcard in the function you don't need to set a global variable for it since it's constantly changing:

```
def play_game(apoints: int, bpoints: int):
    ...


if __name__ == __main__:
    apoints = 0
    bpoints = 0
    play_game(apoints, bpoints)
```

Comment: +1 for giving him a solution avoiding the use of global objects, but he'd have to have play_game in a loop which I assume you left out just for example purposes.

Comment: -1 This won't work without a `global` statement.  Python doesn't work like that.

Comment: @flornquake you dont need the global statements because the value of acard and bcard are being set inside the function and referenced only inside that function, so they don't need to be carried anywhere.

Comment: If you call `play_game(apoints, bpoints)` multiple times, it won't work as you seem to expect it should.